# XSD: Different maxOccurs for specific substitute

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a simple XML structure that looks as follows

```xml
...
<param>
  <name>foo</name>
  <type1>
     Some complex content
  </type1>
</param>
<param>
  <name>bar</name>
  <type2>
     Some complex content
  </type2>
</param>
...
```

The schema I use looks like this

```xml
...
<xs:complexType name="par">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element ref="typeSpecific"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="typeSpecific" abstract="true"/>
<xs:element name="type1" type="t1" substitutionGroup="typeSpecific"/>
<xs:element name="type2" type="t2" substitutionGroup="typeSpecific"/>
...
```

I want to extend this so that if I use type1 in a param, I can only have one such element, but if I use type2 I can have many, like this:

```xml
...
<param>
  <name>bar</name>
  <type2>
     Some complex content
  </type2>
  ...
  <type2>
     Some other complex content
  </type2>
</param>
```

I want to avoid wrapping the `type2` elements in a container because of compatibility issues. My first impulse was to use a `maxOccurs="unbounded"` attribute `<xs:element name="type2" type="t2" substitutionGroup="typeSpecific" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`, but this is not allowed.

Is there any way to enforce this restriction with XSD using my current structure? Can I in some way use `<xs:choice>` instead of substitution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD 1.0 doesn't allow the type of one element to depend on the content of another.

You can implement such dependencies in XSD 1.1 using assertions.

**EDIT:**
You can't do this with substitution groups: if the elements are substitutable for each other, then the occurrence constraints for both must be the same. You'll need an explicit content model with a choice in it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I fail to see how there exists a dependency on the content of another element - isn't it merely a question of the number of allowed elements of two different types? Maybe I have got something wrong on a conceptual level, could you please explain in a little more detail?

Comment: OK, sorry, I should have read more carefully. You can't do this with substitution groups: if the elements are substitutable for each other, then the occurrence constraints for both must be the same. You'll need an explicit content model with a choice in it.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you for revisiting.